# How do I call a function from my library that is marked with a decorator?

Tags: python, python-3.x, events, decorator, python-decorators

How do libraries call functions marked with decorators?
example:

```
@client.event
async def on_ready():
   print(f'{client.user} has connected to Discord!')
```

How is this implemented inside the library?
I tried to do something, but I think there is an easier way.

```
def None_type():
    pass

on_connect_var = None_type


def on_connect(func):
    global on_connect_var
    on_connect_var = func

...
on_connect_var()
...
```

```
@event_manager.on_connect
def on_connect():
    print("Connected!")
```

How to make it easier?

Comment: That's essentially the structure of it. But instead of setting a global variable, it stores the function in an attribute of the `client` instance.

Comment: How much easier do you think it can get? The decorator is only 2 lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

This might help explain how decorators work better than I can do here: https://henryiii.github.io/level-up-your-python/notebooks/2.3%20Decorators.html

The idea is that decorators use function composition, you have a function which returns another function (here `client.event`) that you use to decorate another function (here `on_ready`). In your example,

```py
@client.event
async def on_ready():
   print(f'{client.user} has connected to Discord!')
```

When you later call `on_ready()` you're really calling `client.event(on_ready)()`

Not quite sure how to make your particular example "easier" but hopefully that answers the question of how decorators work?

Comment: I know how decorators work, just how to make events with them, as in the example, that's what I asked